# Trying to share a wireless link wlan0 on PC with a NIC fed to a HUB. LAN hosts are unable to reach router

Tags: linux, routing

I have tried assigning static IP to NIC on eth0 (10.0.0.129). eth0 is able to ping wlan0 (10.0.0.100). eth0 able to ping a host H1 (10.0.0.149) on the HUB. However, eth0 is NOT able to ping the router (10.0.0.1) or reach the internet. Should I have eth0 (and the rest of the LAN) on a separate address segment different from 10.0.0.x? What do I need to do so that H1 and others on the HUB have access to internet?  It looks like eth0 needs to act like a router. I thought having all machines on same address segment will be easier.

Comment: It is hard to see what you are doing, may be impossible (it is hard to tell). However you will need a router if you want to route between segments. The router will have to be in separate segments. When you improve your question, include: Why you want separate segments, the topology of your network, IP-address masks, any thing else so that we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming eth0 is `10.0.0.*/24` and wlan0 is also `10.0.0.*/24`: This is **not going to work**, no matter what you try: Bridging (this is a FAQ) doesn't work, because you need 4-address-mode in the WLAN. Routing doesn't work, because you have segments with the same address range.

> Should I have eth0 (and the rest of the LAN) on a separate address segment different from 10.0.0.x?

Yes, if your whole network setup (which you didn't tell us anything about) allows this.

(TL;DR for network questions: First, draw a picture of the network setup, and include it in the question).

> What do I need to do so that H1 and others on the HUB have access to internet?

I have no idea what your "HUB" is, because you didn't tell us.

The following network setup does work, and may or may not be what you want:

```
        WLAN                             LAN
     10.0.1.*/24                     10.0.2.*/24
          |                               |
          |                               |
  ISP     |                               +---- [Other PC]
router ---+                               |
10.0.1.1  |                               |
          | wlan0              eth0       |
          +------ [ Some PC ] ------------+
          | 10.0.1.100       10.0.2.129   |
          |                               |
          :                               :
```

Where "Some PC" is configured to do network address translation (NAT) on outgoing connections from `eth0` to `wlan0`, and has as default gateway the ISP router `10.0.1.1`. While other machines in the LAN, e.g. "Other PC", have a default route of `10.0.2.129` to "Some PC". You can set this default route for example by running a DHCP server on "Some PC".

There are many variations of this, including no NAT, and routes distributed by the DHCP server of the LAN segment.